# ng-model using ng-options to get property value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-options

Here is my code

```
var filter1 = { id: 96, name: "Affinity Groups Allowed In Site",typeId: 74, description: "SiteAffinityGroupsAllowed" };

var filter2 = { id: 125, name: "AffinityLob", typeId: 100, description: "AffinityLob" };

$scope.filterCriteriaObjets = [filter1, filter2];
```

I am trying to get the name using ng-model but it seems the ng model is getting the whole object . Here is my dropdown

```
<select class="form-control" name="role" ng model="filterCriteria.ObjectName"
ng-options="item as item.name for item in filterCriteriaObjets" ng-required="true" ng-change="getObjectInfo()">
<option value="">- Select Filter Name -</option>
</select>
```

But when I change the option filterCriteria.ObjectName is getting the whole object. I want the ng-model to be equals just the name property

Comment: Try ng-options="item.name for item in filterCriteriaObjects"

Answer (score 2):

here is what you can do...

```
 <select class="form-control" name="role" ng-model="filterCriteria.ObjectName"
    ng-options="item.name as item.name for item in filterCriteriaObjets" ng-required="true" ng-change="getObjectInfo()">
    <option value="">- Select Filter Name -</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: as @Sa E Chowdary also told, that (ng model ==> ng-model) is a problem as well in your html snippet

Comment: hey @Gilberto, please mark this as answer if this solved your problem. thanks.

Comment: hey @Gilberto, please mark this as answer if this solved your problem. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

your error is declaring `ng-model` you  declared it as `ng model`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.12/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.9"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>
    <select class="form-control" name="role" ng-model="filterCriteria.ObjectName"
    ng-options="item.name as item.name for item in filterCriteriaObjets" ng-required="true" ng-change="getObjectInfo()">
    <option value="">- Select Filter Name -</option>
    </select>
    
  </body>
<script>
  var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  var filter1 = { id: 96, name: "Affinity Groups Allowed In Site",typeId: 74, description: "SiteAffinityGroupsAllowed" };

var filter2 = { id: 125, name: "AffinityLob", typeId: 100, description: "AffinityLob" };

$scope.filterCriteriaObjets = [filter1, filter2];

});

  </script>
</html>
```